# int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier when no int usage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error when there is absolutely no usage of int anywhere.

I have this stored procedure

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_GetFileGuid] @fileType varchar(25)
 as 
 select [id] from fileTypes where dirId = @fileType
```

Here id is a uniqueidentifier in fileTypes table

When I execute the following

```
 declare @fileGuid uniqueidentifier
 exec @fileGuid = usp_GetFileGuid 'accounts'
 print @fileGuid
```

I get the following error

```
 (1 row(s) affected)
 Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_GetFileGuid, Line 0
 Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier
```

Is there anything wrong with the syntax of assigning output of stored procedure to the local variable? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `EXEC @fileGuid = procedure` syntax which is used for retrieving *return* values, not resultsets. Return values are restricted to `INT` and should only be used to return status / error codes, not data.

What you want to do is use an `OUTPUT` parameter:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_GetFileGuid] 
  @fileType varchar(25),
  @id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT @id = [id] from dbo.fileTypes where dirId = @fileType;
  -- if the procedure *also* needs to return this as a resultset:
  SELECT [id] = @id;
END
GO
```

Then for usage:

```
declare @fileGuid uniqueidentifier;
exec dbo.usp_GetFileGuid @fileType = 'accounts', @id = @fileGuid OUTPUT;
print @fileGuid;
```

Comment: Thank you. I am sure this is just a piece of cake for you. I am transitioning from write simple select statements to writing procedure :)

Answer (score 1):

The value returned is an int as it is the status of the execution

From [CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

> Return a status value to a calling procedure or batch to indicate
> success or failure (and the reason for failure).

You are looking for an output parameter.

> OUT | OUTPUT
>
> Indicates that the parameter is an output parameter. Use
> OUTPUT parameters to return values to the caller of the procedure.
> text, ntext, and image parameters cannot be used as OUTPUT parameters,
> unless the procedure is a CLR procedure. An output parameter can be a
> cursor placeholder, unless the procedure is a CLR procedure. A
> table-value data type cannot be specified as an OUTPUT parameter of a
> procedure.

Answer (score 1):

```
 create procedure [dbo].[usp_GetFileGuid] @fileType varchar(25),@uuid uniqueidentifier output
 as 
 select @uuid=[id] from fileTypes where dirId = @fileType 

 declare @fileGuid uniqueidentifier
 exec usp_GetFileGuid 'accounts',@fileGuid output
 print @fileGuid
```